# How to use voting results to boost relevance for solr search?

Tags: search

I am using search api with the solr backend to index thousands of nodes. All of them have votes (vote api). Now I am wondering how to boost the relevance of these notes by their vote. I don't want to sort the result completely by votes (this would be easy), but that the votes boost the node's relevance for a certain percentage. Is that possible? How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the voting api results in your apache solr index?
If you do and they are stored under a name ss_votingapi, here is what you need to do:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_apachesolr_query_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
  $query->addParam('fl', 'ss_votingapi');
  $query->addParam('bf', "recip(rord(ss_votingapi),1, 1000, 1000)");
}
```

More [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_increase_the_score_for_specific_documents), [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#recip) and [here](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_query_alter/7)

Comment: My problem is, that I do not use Apachesolr module but Search API with Solr extension. Does anybody know what would be the equivalent of $query->addParam for Search API? Can't find it.